# Firefox pseudo-element ignoring overflow-x

Tags: css, firefox, sass, overflow, pseudo-element

[image: What the issue looks like]

As shown in the image above, Firefox ignores the `overflow-x: hidden` that is placed on the `html` element directly. Resulting in mobile users being able to scroll horizontally and viewing a large empty whitespace across the entire webpage. In every other browser, I do not have this issue.

You can check/test this out yourself at [digitalshovel.com](https://digitalshovel.com)

The only thing that resolves this is removing the pseudo-element entirely. I was hoping for a better fix, if anyone has any better suggestions.

Comment: Please note that [providing a link to your site is not sufficient](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428). Paste your code here as text so as to make a [mre].